MapStruct loops generating code when more than eight parameters to a method
Having to pass all the Mappers I need for @AfterMapping methods to the main method caused an error in MapStruct. If I pass more than eight to the method causes
error: Internal error in the mapping processor: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space      
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:156)     
at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.model.source.selector.TypeSelector.getCandidateParameterBindingPermutations(TypeSelector.java:185)         
at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.model.source.selector.TypeSelector.getMatchingMethods(TypeSelector.java:51)        
at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.model.source.selector.MethodSelectors.getMatchingMethods(MethodSelectors.java:60)          
at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.creation.MappingResolverImpl$ResolvingAttempt.getBestMatch(MappingResolverImpl.java:495)         
at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.creation.MappingResolverImpl$ResolvingAttempt.getTargetAssignment(MappingResolverImpl.java:234)          
at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.creation.MappingResolverImpl$ResolvingAttempt.access$100(MappingResolverImpl.java:169)   
at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.creation.MappingResolverImpl.getTargetAssignment(MappingResolverImpl.java:145)   
at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.model.PropertyMapping$PropertyMappingBuilder.build(PropertyMapping.java:258)       
at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.model.BeanMappingMethod$Builder.handleDefinedMapping(BeanMappingMethod.java:1474)          
at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.model.BeanMappingMethod$Builder.handleDefinedMappings(BeanMappingMethod.java:1165)         
at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.model.BeanMappingMethod$Builder.build(BeanMappingMethod.java:292)          
at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MapperCreationProcessor.getMappingMethods(MapperCreationProcessor.java:427)      
at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MapperCreationProcessor.getMapper(MapperCreationProcessor.java:188)      
at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MapperCreationProcessor.process(MapperCreationProcessor.java:142)        
at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MapperCreationProcessor.process(MapperCreationProcessor.java:85)         
at org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor.process(MappingProcessor.java:400)         
at org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor.processMapperTypeElement(MappingProcessor.java:380)        
at org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor.processMapperElements(MappingProcessor.java:329)   
at org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor.process(MappingProcessor.java:209)         
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.DelegatingProcessor.process(DelegatingProcessor.java:62)    
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.IsolatingProcessor.process(IsolatingProcessor.java:50)      
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.DelegatingProcessor.process(DelegatingProcessor.java:62)    
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.TimeTrackingProcessor.access$401(TimeTrackingProcessor.java:37)     
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.TimeTrackingProcessor$5.create(TimeTrackingProcessor.java:99)       
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.TimeTrackingProcessor$5.create(TimeTrackingProcessor.java:96)       
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.TimeTrackingProcessor.track(TimeTrackingProcessor.java:117)         
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.TimeTrackingProcessor.process(TimeTrackingProcessor.java:96)        
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1021)   
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:937)      
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1265)       
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1380)  


Please share some code. We would like to help you, but we firstly need to check what you have done.
